# Write Reducer output of a Mapreduce job to a single File

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have written a map-reduce job for the data in HBase. It contains multiple mappers and just a single reducer. The Reducer method takes in the data supplied from the mapper and do some analytic on it. After the processing is complete for all the data in  HBase I wanted to write the data back to a file in HDFS through the single Reducer. Presently I am able to write the data to HDFS every time I get new one but unable to figure how to write the final conclusion to HDFS only at last.

Comment: Do you want to export the HBase Table data to a HDFS file?

Comment: I am using Map-Reduce job to read data in parallel. But I use single reducer to do the analytics and at last write it back to HDFS. Which may contain some conclusions about the HBASE data not the tuples.

Comment: Check I've posted an answer if it helps.

Comment: I don't need Hbase data on the HDFS. I want to do the analytic of the data in the Reducer method and the conclusion of all results need to written on the HDFS only after the last processing.

Comment: So, when you do a job.setNumReduceTasks(1); doensn't it do the trick for you? That will force a single reducer.

Comment: What do you mean by this - "write to data to HDFS every time I get new one"?

Comment: That would force a single reducer but in the reducer method I am using some static variables which get updated on new data. So how to write those variables in a file on HDFS only after last processing.

Comment: I mean to say that conclusion of each tuple is written each time to a file on HDFS but I need to write the conclusion of all the tuples and only at last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you trying to write a final result from a single reducer to HDFS, you can try any one of the approaches below -

1. Use Hadoop API FileSystem's create() function to write to HDFS from the reducer.
2. Emit a single key and value from reducer after the final calculation
3. Override Reducers cleanup() function and do point (1) there.

Details on 3:

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html#cleanup-org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context-

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have same problem, but I have to do the second option. The thing is how do I know if all the task have finished? I tried to look at Hadoop API but couldn't find any method. Can you please guide me?I was thinking to overwrite output file, is it the feasible solution?

Comment: @Marco167: Are you using a single reducer? You can probably then iterating though the values, calculate everything and write to HDFS only once at last using context.write().

Comment: Thank you, well I'm doing it exactly the same way. But since the variables are static and I couldn't get when ALL the tasks have finished so I could write the final solution(which is propagating inside static HashMap) with context.write()?

I meant, Is there any method which signify that now there is no input left for processing, so print the final result?

Comment: I think I am not able to explain my question. My apologies!

Actually how do I know if final calculation is reached? I mean to say that now all the data has passed to reducer.

Like ReducerTaskCompleted()?

Comment: @Marco167, As I have already mentioned, you can iterate through the iterable the reduce function provide and as you iterate, do the calculations, put it the HashMap and when you finished iterating, emit whatever you've got in the HashMap using context.write(). Does that help now?

Comment: Actually HashMap will keep itself updating on every task. It will get finished when each and every task has reached the reducer.

PS: I am using two parallel maps and 1 reducer.
For example: I have data of movies and actors. It is a possibility that in input number 23,78 and 100 the relevant information is present. So I could not emit the output until and unless 100 is reached. But this is very simple example. My data is very complex

Comment: OK - now, I can understand, so you are saying, you want to have some kind of a global hashmap that you'll keep on updating from each map and reduce task? And finally emit when all task(maps/reducers) completes?

Comment: Yes exactly!But my hashmap is local to reducer.
Because this hashmap insertions have nothing to do with mappers. I receive mappers output correctly.

Comment: Yeah, then great, then whatever I have told you earlier should work. You have a HashMap local to your reducer, which you update upon iterating the iterable object you receive in the reduce function. Then when you are done with the iteration you emit only once.
Pseudo code:
`reduce(Key key, Iterable<T> values) { HashMap map = new HashMap(); for(T value: values ) {   //update map.put() }; context.write(); } `

Comment: @ SSaikia_JtheRocker: Thanks for your effort. I have figured out some other method of achieving my results.